# Jquery Find first h1 on a page and append more html to its html

Tags: jquery, html, append

How can I find first h1 on a page and append more html to its html? I am trying something like this and it is giving me error -

```
 var str = $('h1:first').html();
    $('h1:first').html(str.append('some more html '));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** can take the `function` as **argument**, and **return** from it `current html` with added `new html`.

```
$('h1:first').html(function(){
  return $(this).html() + ' some more html';
});
```

Comment: @itsgoingdown it gives me ' unterminated string literal' error . I have something like this in the string that I am adding there...`<!-- Alert --> <a class="dialogM" href="/alerts/medsalert.html" title="alert"> <img src="/images/alert.gif"></a> `

Comment: @Kaur Check that example here :http://jsbin.com/vigeho/edit?html,js,output   also inspect that first h1, it has proper html inside

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why it is not working in my real code. I will keep trying

Comment: @itsgoingdown I have had some additional images and needed to strip the spaces from the html before appending. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$('h1:first').html($('h1:first').html() + 'some more html');
```

You can put the string on variable like your code

```
var str = $('h1:first').html();
$('h1:first').html(str + 'some more html');
```